# WordPress Single Quote JSON Issue

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress

In a WordPress shortcode function, I have the following:

```
$args=shortcode_atts( array(
   'setting1' => 'value1',
   'setting2' => 'value2'
), $atts);


return '<div data-myData=\'{' . json_encode( $args ) . '}\' ></div>';
```

I'm trying to retrieve the arguments and return a string of HTML. That html should look like:

```
<div data-myData='{ "setting1" : "value1" , "setting2" : "value2" }'></div>
```

Then some JS picks it up from there.
However, it seems that however I approach this, WP keeps converting my single quotes to double quotes on the **data-myData attribute** and I wind up with this:

```
<div data-myData="{ "setting1" : "value1" , "setting2" : "value2" }"></div>
```

Is there something simple I'm missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting JSON into an html context, so you need to use HTML-specific quoting methods:

```
return '<div data-myData="' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode( $args )) . '"></div>';
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That still doesn't seem to produce the single quotes on the data-myData attribute...

Comment: why do you need single quotes? double-quote are the preferred quotes for html attributes.

Comment: I'm inserting JSON as the attribute value and need single quotes for the outside - which is valid.

Comment: which is where htmlspecial chars comes in. the double-quotes in the json will become `&quote;`, so you'll end up with `data-Mydata="&quote;foo&quote;"`

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't what I'm asking for. I'm currently passing a JSON object to a JS file which works 100%. I'm needing to build a string containing this html in php now. The only condition being that the outside quotes on the attribute value need to be single quotes. Inside the quotes is all taken care of already.